# Why does Network library fails to detect when internet is connected back in Swift Ios

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I have the following code to detect my internet connection state

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    internetStatus()
    
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
 }
 func internetStatus(){

    let nwPathMonitor = NWPathMonitor()
    nwPathMonitor.start(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "network_monitor"))
    nwPathMonitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
       
        if (path.status == .satisfied){
            if (path.usesInterfaceType(.wifi)){
                print("wifi")
            }
            if (path.usesInterfaceType(.cellular)){
                print("cellular")
            }
        }
        if (path.status == .unsatisfied)
        {
            print("noConnection")
        }
        if (path.status == .requiresConnection){
            
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine but on iOs simulator I am unable to detect reconnects. When I disconnect "noConnection" is printed which fine but when I connect "noConnection" prints again. Is this some sort of bug or there is something wrong in my code

Comment: "when interent is connected"?  "to detect my interent connection state"?

Comment: It print wifi, then when I disconnect it prints noConnection then when I reconnect it prints noConnection Again

Comment: Sorry I dont get what do you mean

Comment: it is does-not work. It was just working fine before I updated myMacBook to BigSur Could this be the issue. I tried with reachability too and it is the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this works fine on real device but on simulator it doesnot work. I am using macos Big Sur and XCode 12.5